# Tile Based UI inside windows 8 store app

Tags: xaml, windows-8, tile

I am creating window 8 store app that will run on windows 8 tablets,
In my application I want to give tile based UI, 
Can any one guide, how will it be possible or is there any controls available like HubTile Control for WP7... ?

Thanks And Regards,
:)

Comment: Doesn't Visual Studio 2012 contain tile based project templates???

Comment: Nope, There is not any template available ...

Comment: This may help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868260.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Telerik has released the Windows 8 controls which includes the Hub tile as you mentioned for WP 7.

Check it out : http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-metro/controls/hubtile.aspx

Comment: So all the applications on windows store using tiles are depending only on Telerik??

Comment: No. There are other vendors such as Syncfusion also provides similar controls. At that time when I was posting this update, there was no other controls than Telerik. Here is a link to Syncfusion - http://www.syncfusion.com/products/winrt/controls